# python script for feeding input of another script line by line from some other file

Tags: python, bash

Currently I am using bash script to handle input (from a file `inputs.txt`) to a python script with the command `./run.sh input.txt`

```
{
while read line
do
    echo $line;
done < $1
} | python main.py
```

The content of my file `input.txt`

```
string input 1
string input 2
string input 3
string input 4
string input 5
the end
```

I have to put `the end` at last because I get error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    print raw_input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

This is working fine but sometimes I work on windows. Can I write a **python script** to handle such scripts by inputting line by line. I cannot modify the code of the original script.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham that's my python script that takes input. let's say there are 5 raw inputs there.

Comment: how does `input.txt` fit into it?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham [check this](http://i.imgur.com/9O5HEWs.png?1) out. I have slightly modified the file name.

Comment: @Padraic has a point: there are a few different ways to do this, which may or may not work depending on the contents of `main.py`. So it would be useful to see that contents.

Comment: If you cannot change main   use a python script, open input.txt and pass the file object to sdtin `print(subprocess.check_output(["python","main.py"],stdin=f))`

Comment: That will work on windows and linux

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thats exactly what I am looking for!! [This works smoothly](http://i.imgur.com/AbYgaUI.png?1)